# Azure Cosmos Db Materialized View

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

For context:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/announcing-materialized-view-feature-for-azure-cosmos-db-nosql-preview/

In materialized view are we still bound by logical partition size limit of 20 GB? If we are having a unique key (high cardinality value) as the partition key in the materialized view target container which is read only there can be potentially billions of logical partitions (also items) based on the workload. But since the materialized view container is read only and we know the partition key in the search we can do a read item and can escape the cross partition scenario in the target container.

Do we have a limit to the number of logical partitions being created? Since we are not writing to the logical partitions in the materialized view hot partition scenario is not rising but considering our workload we can have billions of unique items based on the partition key(the unique id that is selected).Will that cause a potential limitation down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Materialized View containers are similar to the normal containers in all aspects except that they are read-only containers for the applications. Just like the case with normal containers, you can have UNLIMITED number of distinct (logical) partition keys.